# I want to change the size of my JFrame Panel to the size of selected image here is my code

Tags: java, swing, jframe

here is my code

---

i have attached the images of output and the required result can anyone help me with this
i'll be very thankful

```
private void jButton1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      
        FileNameExtensionFilter fnef = new FileNameExtensionFilter("IMAGES", "png", "jpg", "jpeg");
        JFileChooser ImageFile = new JFileChooser();
        ImageFile.addChoosableFileFilter(fnef);
        int openDialog = ImageFile.showOpenDialog(null);
        if (openDialog == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            File choosenFile = ImageFile.getSelectedFile();
            String choosenFilePath = choosenFile.getAbsolutePath();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, choosenFilePath);
            //displaying the image 
            ImageIcon imgIcon = new ImageIcon(choosenFilePath);
            //getting the height width of the image 
            Image image = imgIcon.getImage().getScaledInstance(imgIcon.getIconWidth(), imgIcon.getIconHeight(), Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
            NewJFrame mainFrame =new NewJFrame();
            JLabelImage.setIcon(new ImageIcon(image));
            JLabelImage.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(imgIcon.getIconWidth(),imgIcon.getIconHeight()));
            mainFrame.pack();
            mainFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            mainFrame.setVisible(true);
        }
        
    }
```

i'm supposed to get like this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JKgFj.png]

Getting this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMCwO.png]

Comment: If you want the JLabelImage to show in the mainFrame you should add it to this frame

Comment: i want the mainframe to change it size according to the size of the image

Comment: but the problem you don't add the image to your frame, so nothing will show

Comment: 1. Load the image;
 2. Gather all the information required for that image and store it into a List Interface or something of a similar concept;
 3. Display the image sized to accommodate the container which has been
    previously initialized to a specific size to suite your GUI. Google... "Resize Image to fit JLabel with Java".

Comment: There is no need to scale the image and there is no need to set the preferred size of the label. Swing components will determine their own preferred size. Use `ImageIO` to read images. You will get an error message if the image is not found.